# Getting values from different classes

Tags: c#, class

Problem is in my class that renders the level that needs some value to render the side scrolling and this value im getting inside the player class.. And when i make something like:

```
//Inside the render class
//This is global variable
Player player = new Player;

//This is inside some method that renders.
public void rendering method()
{
int i = player.myInt;
}
```

Int i is always zero.. Even i update myInt inside the player class every time the right button is pressed.

I also tried making a method that returns the value i need:

```
//Inside the player class
public int testing()

{
      return myValue;
}
```

This is also not working correctly..

Inside my Player class i have the variable inside the constructor like:

```
public Player()
{
myValue = 0;
}
```

And then inside a update method inside the player class that gets called to look for keypresses i have:

```
public void Update()
{
 if(key left was pressed)
    myValue--;
}
```

Comment: What do you do in your constructor for the `Player` class? How do you persist your `Player` objects?

Comment: myInt = integer2; the integer two gets updated every keypress.

Comment: Are you certain that the `Player` object created in your example doesn't go away between keypresses? That's sure what it looks like.

Comment: But is your `player` object still in scope?  In addition, what is the scope of the `player` object - how long is it around during the execution of your program.  Something tells me the object `player` is gone by the time you need it.

Comment: No i initated the player object at the global variables.

Comment: Quite simply, you have not given us enough information to help.

Comment: I updated now to make it more clear to you people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct format.

For example:

```
class Player: Form
{
    public static int myInt = 0;    //This is where the next screen should be.

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public Player()
    {
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Changes MyInt.  Increments myInt so the next corod
    /// </summary>
    private void ButtonPressed()
    {
        myInt++;
        //Note, you need to get the screen size and mode it with this to prevent setting the location off screen.

    }
}

class Render
{
    private Player player;  //Class variable so it persists between calls

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Sets player.
    /// </summary>
    public Render()
    {
        Location = new Point(Player.myInt, Player.myInt);           //Set my coordinate
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the value of this.player.MyInt in a message box.
    /// </summary>
    public void rendering_method()
    {
        int i = Player.myInt;

        MessageBox.Show("The value is: " + i);
    }
}
```

If that does not resolve your problem then we will need more info.
It would be best if you could put up the two classes affected.

Updated to set Player location using constructor.
Updated based on updated content in original question.  What is the object hierarchy?  Will the Player be creating the Render class?

Comment: The problem is that when i want to use MyInt outside the Player class its zero all the time.. This int isgoing to represent a cordinate to render too.. And thats why im doing MyInt++ when button is pressed.. I dont want MyInt to be zero in the other class. Hope yo understand when i explain like this.

Comment: Ur latest update to your answear do not help. I can't use it if its not inside the constructor.

Comment: Why can you not use it unless it is in the constructor?  I assume "it" is the myInt variable and the Constructor is the "Player" class's constructor.  The problem with setting myInt in the constructor is that every time a new instance of the Player class is made, it will reset the myInt value.  If you are only creating one instance of the class then you should be fine use MyInt as shown before.